# "suggested edits pending approval" notification should be hidden if you can't review edits

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

Today I have reviewed 20 edits, so I cannot review any more. However, that tempting little badge next to the "review" link in the top-right corner continues to update and be visible, which is somewhat irritating.

Can this be hidden from view if the user cannot review any further? Otherwise, it's a bit of a distraction :)